# AttachConsole() and ShowWindow() equivalent in Mono

Tags: .net, ubuntu, mono

I am porting a Windows C# application to run on Linux. The application makes use of PInvoke calls to windows system libs - which are not available on Linux.

Here is a snippet of the code section I am having problems porting:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
        private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr HWND, int CMDSHOW);

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);


            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Are there similar functions in the mono framework?. If no, how may I implement similar behaviour on Mono?. I am running on Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS

Comment: What do those APIs _do_?

Comment: @sarnold They're documented on MSDN.microsoft.com...

Comment: Should state exactly what you would like to achieve, instead of saying Windows APIs. Unless the reader knows Windows very well, even MSDN is useless.

Comment: Don't think there is direc maping to unix world where you can have a lot of terminal emulators. Try runing terminal as child process and redirect io or this ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1086370